# Build my specific REgular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression for a specific problem but I cannot achieve to do it. I have a structure of a string like this `01422756860-8`.

As you can see there is a string of length 13. The first 11 characters should be numbers in the interval of [0-9], the next character is a line(minus) and the last character is again a number. There shouldn be any space in between these characters.

Could anyone please help me to do this? I am going to use this regex in php.

I look forward on your answer.
Thank You.

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: `\d{11}-\d`, or whatever PHP calls that.

Comment: `-` is called a dash :).

Comment: This is about as basic as regex gets. What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because this is a trivial problem and you haven't show any effort to resolve it yourself. A basic knowledge of regex should make this easy, so if there is something specific you're struggling with, you need to show what you've tried and explain how it's failing. If you don't have the basic knowledge of regex, StackOverflow is not the place to find a tutorial or to get someone else to do your work for you. You're better off learning regex first, and then coming here with specific problems you're having.

Comment: You can downvote but it is not fair. I needed it today and it was not my best time to stop and study on regular expressions. Anyway it is up to you. My problem was not only the regular expression itself but also the php code. Anyway thnx a lot :):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem?

```
/^[0-9]{11}-[0-9]$/
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tA6pD3)

Autopsy:

- `^` *The string **must** start here*
- `[0-9]{11}` *Any digit from 0 to 9 repeated exactly 11 times*
- `-` *A literal dash*
- `[0-9]` *Any single digit from 0 to 9*
- `$` *The string **must** end here*

Comment: Autopsy thnx a lot. You are great. Actually I always had problems with Regular Expressions :D. Maybe because I never stopped to learn them from scratch in details. I still cant understand why :):). Anyway thnx for your answers

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should do it

```
\d{11}-\d
```